# Fast numerical integration of an integral of the form $\int_{[0,\:1)^d}\left|f\right|\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}$

Tags: numerical-methods, lebesgue-integral, numerical-calculus

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $p:[0,1)^d\to[0,\infty)$ be Lebesgue integrable, $\sigma>0$, $$\varphi(x,y):=p(x)e^{-\frac{\|x-y\|^2}{\sigma^2}}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in[0,1)^d$$ and $$A(x,y):=\sum_{i=1}^k\varphi(x_i,y)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in([0,1)^d)^k\text{ and }y\in[0,1)^d$$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. Now, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, $$E(x):=\int_{[0,\:1)^d}\left|A(x,\;\cdot\;)-p\right|\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}.\tag1$$ Note that $$\nabla_{x_i}E(x)=\int_{[0,\:1)^d}\operatorname{sgn}(A(x,y)-p(y))e^{-\frac{\|x_i-y\|^2}{\sigma^2}}\left(\nabla p(x_i)+2p(x_i)\frac{y-x_i}{\sigma^2}\right)\:\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}y)\tag2.$$

> **Question**: I want to numerically compute $(1)$ and $(2)$. At the moment, I do this on a regular grid, but both the error$^1$ and the computation time is very bad when $k$ is large.
>
> What is the "state-of-the-art" approach to compute this?

---

$^1$ Assume for example that each $x_i$ on the grid used for the numerical computation; then $E(x)$ will be computed as $0$; which is clearly dramatically wrong.

Comment: Without assuming any regularity of $p$, the best you can do is Monte-Carlo (though even then an estimate of the error will involve the $L^2$ norm).

Comment: Even with more regularity ( I spotted a $\nabla p$ somewhere) MC is a good starting point. It is really easy, comes with a simple estimate for the error and is scalable. You did not mention size of $d$ and $k$ and your threshold for the error. If MC does not work for you, you should clarify these parameters in your question.

Comment: @fedja Monte-Carlo or should I do quasi-Monte Carlo; using a Sobol sequence, for example?